# Squarespace navigation customising

Tags: squarespace

does anyone know how to make my secondary navigation background black in Squarespace? I'm using the Brine template, there doesn't seem to be a way to alter it, only to alter the whole header.
Thanks!

Comment: can you please add some relevant information to your question? maybe some code or and image of what you want to achieve

Comment: if you can share a demo URL for the site you'll surely get help with the CSS needed to customize the secondary nav. Their demo theme doesn't have a secondary menu on the right https://brine-demo.squarespace.com/blog-brine. If you can describe where on the demo theme I linked that might be enough context, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using the inspector tool and target the selector then change the color in the custom css panel.
for example

```
.header-nav-folder {
background-color:#000000;
}
```